# Is there a way to access Apple's 2FA Verification Code via Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, password, keychain, two-factor-authentication

I would like to script accessing the built-in two factor authentication code that is accessed via System Preferences -> Passwords. One of the apps I use does not prompt for the 2FA code so each time I use it I have to do several clicks to retrieve the code. I am aware there is a mechanism to access Keychain items, but not the 2FA passwords. Does anyone know if there is a way to access these codes via terminal?

Note: I'm not referring to Apple's own 2FA service to verify Apple ID accounts.

[image: Screenshot]